# Using Scrapy in Jupyter notebook / accessing response directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, jupyter-notebook

I want to directly interact with a Scrapy `response` object in a Jupyter notebook, the same way you can after entering the [Scrapy shell](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) by typing `scrapy shell "some-url"` in the command line.

In a notebook, I can run these commands without error:

```
import scrapy
request = scrapy.Request("some-url")
response = scrapy.http.Response("some-url")
```

But `request` and `response` both have an empty body property. According to the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

> Typically, Request objects are generated in the spiders and pass
>   across the system until they reach the Downloader, which executes the
>   request and returns a Response object which travels back to the spider
>   that issued the request.

It seems I'm missing the step where "the Downloader" executes a request object and returns a Response object. I can't figure out how that works.

Does anyone know what happens when you run `scrapy shell "some-url"`in the command line, so I can replicate those steps in a a Jupyter notebook?

**Note**: A very similar question [was posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177620/how-to-execute-scrapy-shell-url-with-notebook), and the given answer works for me, but using the additional, third-party "Requests" library seems unnecessary/ non-ideal.

Comment: You could have used scrapy shell

Comment: your third-party requests library is actually an integral part of  python ;)
btw you can also execute bash ´!scrapy shell "some-url"in´ from jupyter

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @Umair, I want to use Jupyter instead of the scrapy shell so I can more easily save/modify the commands I try. @Zephro, `urllib.request` is built-in, but they were using `requests` which must be installed separately. And ex`!scrapy shell "some-url"` doesn't work because it tries to launch a shell inside the cell and freezes the notebook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can approach the problem this way

```
import requests
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

res = requests.get('some-url')
response = TextResponse(res.url, body=res.text, encoding='utf-8')
```